# Replace URL except in anchor tag Jascript Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using JavaScript/jQuery Regex for replacing URLs. It works perfect but i want not to replace URL that are in anchor tag.
My current code:

```
function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /^(!href=")\w(((\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/)|(www\.))[^\s]+)/g;
    //var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function (url, b, c) {
        var url2 = (c == 'www.') ? 'http://' + url : url;
        return '<a href="' + url2 + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
    })
}

str='http://www.google.com and <a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>';
urlify(str);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parse the string and filter the `textNode`s.

Comment: can you explain your answer?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. There are DOM manipulation functions that you can use to find the anchor tags.

Comment: i just want to get all accept that are in anchor tag. By following your scenario i have to write and test a lot.

Comment: if you want `<a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>` to go to http://www.yahoo.com, that wont work (I am assuming this is true).  Fixing that would help in coming up with a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the text minus the anchor tag by doing something like this:

```js
str='http://www.google.com and <a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>';

var e = document.createElement("div");
e.innerHTML = str;

alert(e.innerText);
```

Now you can use your regex to identify the url and replace it in the original text.